# $\pi_0$ in arbitrary category of simplicial objects

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category (let it be pointed and cocomplete) such that the category of simplicial objects $s\mathcal C$ is a model category. In particular, I'm interested in two cases:

1. $\mathcal C$ is an "algebraic" category with some notion of exactness, which satisfy conditions of Quillen's theorem II.4
2. $\mathcal C$ is a model category itself - in this case things may depend on the chosen model structure on $s\mathcal C$.

As far as I understand, for any $X\in s\mathcal C$ we can define $\pi_0 X$ as a quotient of $X_0$ by some equivalence relation and in case of fibrant $X$, $\pi_0 X=\mathrm{coeq}\{X_1\rightrightarrows X_0\}$ - so, restricted to fibrant objects, $\pi_0$ is a left adjoint to an inclusion $\mathcal C\hookrightarrow s\mathcal C$

**Q1** Is it true that $\pi_0$ preserves weak equivalences in case (2) and sends weak equivalences to isomorphisms in case (1)? Maybe in case (2) we should take "homotopy" $\pi_0$ - $\mathrm{hocoeq}$ instead of the ordinary coequalizer. Then the answer should be positive.

**Q2** Let $F\to E\to B$ be a fiber sequence, what can we say about $\pi_0 F\to \pi_0 E\to \pi_0 B$ ? Is it a fiber sequence in case (2) or an exact sequence (exact at $\pi_0 E$) in case (1) ?

Any references are appreciated. I quickly scanned through Quillen's book, but didn't find much.